# opencart - stock status name not updating

Tags: opencart

I got opencart 1.4.9.5 version. I'm changing stock status name in admin in System -> Localisation -> Stock status. It's saved without error but the 'status name' on product page is still the old one.

Even if I change product status to any other it's changed in admin area but in frontend view of the product it's still the same one. Stock id also changes in database. What can be wrong?

Arek

Comment: If you edited Stock statuses in System > Localisation and changed 'Out Of Stock Status' on product details page, then it sounds like a caching problem. delete your browser's cache, also delete Opencart product cache in system/cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the status text is actually defined in a language file in older versions of OpenCart. I think it's the product language file `catalog/language/your-language/product/product.php`. If not, it's `catalog/language/your-language/your-language.php`